# Were Mandela's documents on violence vindicated after the ANC came to power?

Tags: political-history

This is because on the issue of violence that Mandela try to explain in his document did not reach at point that we can say are succeeded. For example racial segregation still exists in South Africa..  So did the ANC government do anything that concern with violence that has been explained by Nelson Mandela in his document?

Comment: Welcome to the site, thank you for asking an unusual and interesting question.  I don't think I understand the question, but it seems rather subjective. Tried to make some edits to help, but I don't understand the question well enough to edit further.  It would also help greatly if you cited the documents on violence.

Comment: Are you asking whether the ANC govt reduced racial violence?

Comment: What document are we talking about? Can we have some kind of reference or link?